# Realistically, are atmospheric physics questions on topic and acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I have very serious doubts from my experience here (albeit, limited).  Two things that I have rightly or wrongly observed from the responses (and lack thereof) to my questions:

The answer I got was only provided when I offered the bounty - without the bounty, I am sure it never would have been answered.

The other questions I posted are not even worth being researched it seems.

(I researched for questions that were out of my subject area, despite being hellishly busy, and naively thought that others would do the same).

Comment: Personally, I'm very much in favour of atmospheric sciences questions. I've asked and answered a few on this site, but I don't know the answers to yours.

Comment: SE doesn't let me comment with <50 points, so I have to write an answer. I am a new member. I have expertise in this area, and would be glad to answer Q's. I am also a member at Earth Sciences. I would suggest Planetary atmospheres over here and Earth's atmosphere over there, except the Ionosphere. ***Edited to add:*** But any atmospheric physics Q is always *acceptable* here.

Answer (score 8):

If they weren't closed, then they are on-topic and acceptable.

Lack of answers just means lack of interest or expertise from others. As I've said many times, the only way to attract people with those interests or expertise is to have something for them to do here and to tell them about it.

You've done the first, now they just need to find out there are things to do here and come do them.

If you can't or don't want to wait, that's on you. But if your questions stayed open then you didn't violate a policy and if they didn't get answered then you didn't excite the right people or the right people aren't here.

Comment: I think I will have far better luck on the Earth Sciences SE when it comes out of incubation

Comment: and yeah, it seems to be a lack of 'interest', as there is considerable research expertise on this site

Comment: I second tgp, here. We're happy to see this stuff, we just don't know enough about it to say anything intelligent.

Comment: You ask good questions, but I think there are few here able to give good answers in your field. The geophysics tag may be followed by a few more people - but you'll have to be open responses from physicists that may not have as much subject expertise as yourself.

Comment: Points taken, time to take my leave (interestingly, i worked out the answers to my questions).

Answer (score 3):

I hope atmospheric physics -as well as all other geophysics- remains on topic somewhere on SE. I think there is less difference between the various disciplines of physical science than the ways we tend to group ourselves. I like the idea of a earth sciences group, but expect it may be too thin. We should use the available tags more effectively.

Comment: Atmospheric and geophysics are on topic on Physics. There is no question about that. They always have been, and presumably always will be. We just don't have many experts in our regular user base.

Comment: @dmckee and seemingly no interest-base either

Comment: @Amaterasu The interest base has to start somewhere. For a very long time the experimental particle physics interest base on the site was me an anna v. The presence of expertise helps to drive interest and *vice versa*, but it may take a while to start to build. I hope you'll check in from time to time so that your interest can be part of that building process.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to hold out until the earth sciences site is up and running